# What is the best way to get the name of the caller class in an object?

Tags: scala

I could get this working using this:

```
scala> object LOGGER {
     | def warning(msg: String)(implicit className:String) = {
     |   className
     | }
     | }
defined object LOGGER

scala> class testing {
     | lazy implicit val className = this.getClass.getName
     | def test = LOGGER.warning("Testing")
     | }
defined class testing

scala> val obj = new testing()
obj: testing = testing@11fb4f69

scala> obj.test
res51: String = testing <=======

scala> class testing2 {
     | lazy implicit val className = this.getClass.getName
     | def test = LOGGER.warning("Testing")
     | }
defined class testing2

scala> val obj2 = new testing2()
obj2: testing2 = testing2@2ca3a203


scala> obj2.test
res53: String = testing2 <=====
```

I also tried using Thread.currentThread.getStackTrace in the `object LOGGER` but couldn't get it to print the calling class `testing` in the `warning` function.
Any other ways to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Dynamic variable

One way to do it is [DymamicVariable](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.util.DynamicVariable)

```
import scala.util.DynamicVariable
object LOGGER {
  val caller = new DynamicVariable[String]("---")
  def time = new Date().toString
  def warning(msg: String) = println(s"[${caller.value} : $time] $msg")
}

trait Logging {
  def logged[T](action: => T) = LOGGER.caller.withValue(this.getClass.getName)(action)
}

class testing extends Logging {
  def test = logged {
    //some actions
    LOGGER.warning("test something")
    //some other actions
  }
}

val t = new testing

t.test
```

will print something like

> [testing : Wed Nov 25 11:29:23 MSK 2015] test something

Or instead of mixing in `Logging` you can use it directly

```
class testing {
  def test = LOGGER.caller.withValue(this.getClass.getName) {
    //some actions
    LOGGER.warning("test something")
    //some other actions
  }
}
```

#### Macro

Another more powerfull, but more complex to support approach is to build some simple [macro](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/quasiquotes/intro.html)

You could define in other source, preferrably in other subproject

```
import scala.reflect.macros.blackbox.Context
import scala.language.experimental.macros
class LoggerImpl(val c: Context) {
  import c.universe._

  def getClassSymbol(s: Symbol): Symbol = if (s.isClass) s else getClassSymbol(s.owner)

  def logImpl(msg: Expr[String]): Expr[Unit] = {
    val cl = getClassSymbol(c.internal.enclosingOwner).toString
    val time = c.Expr[String](q"new java.util.Date().toString")
    val logline = c.Expr[String](q""" "[" + $cl + " : " + $time + "]" + $msg """)
    c.Expr[Unit](q"println($logline)")
  }
}

object Logger {
  def warning(msg: String): Unit = macro LoggerImpl.logImpl
}
```

Now you don't need to change the testing class:

```
class testing {
  def test = {
    //some actions
    Logger.warning("something happen")
    //some other actions
  }
}
```

And see desired output.

Thsi could be very-perfomant alternative to runtime stack introspection

Comment: Can `def logged[T](action: => T)=LOGGER.caller.withValue(this.getClass.getName)(action)` not be done without modifying the testing classes and only the LOGGER class? Because there is a ton of them all across.

Comment: +1 Thanks, but I mean't not touching the testing class def at all and just doing something to the LOGGER object

Comment: Could you please look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34040122/scala-macros-error-not-found-value

Answer (score 0):

I use this technique in my custom classloader project to get the name of the first class up the stack not in my package. The general idea is copied from the UrlClassloader.

```
String callerClassName="";
StackTraceElement[] stackTrace=Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace();
for (int i=1; i < stackTrace.length; i++) {
  String candidateClassName=stackTrace[i].getClassName();
  if(!candidateClassName.startsWith("to.be.ignored") && 
     !candidateClassName.startsWith("java")){
    callerClassName=candidateClassName;
    break;
  }
}
```

The approach has it's drawbacks since it only gets the name of the class, not the actual class or even better the object.

Comment: I understand how to get the class name from getStackTrace, what I don't is how to determine in the `LOGGER` object's `warning` function as in which class has called it.

Comment: This is why my code iterates up the stack until the package isn't my utility package. The first one not in the package named "to.be.ignored" is the right one.